Intermittent Connection Timeout Issues in Java 21/Spring Boot 3.1.6 Application with Multiple API Consumption
We are experiencing intermediate connection timeout issues. I am using Java 21 and Spring Boot version 3.1.6. The application internally calls the Amadeus API to collect data. My application acts as a wrapper for these APIs. We are consuming 35+ APIs, so sometimes we encounter connection timeouts. We have integrated load tests against the Amadeus API, which consistently returns proper responses without any issues. Similar applications are also experiencing the same issue. All these applications are using Java 21, and instead of the Amadeus API, they consume other services as well.
Does anyone have any idea about the issue?
For your reference, I have added the RestTemplate configuration to this question. It would be very helpful for me to find the root cause of this issue.
@Bean(name = "restTemplate")
@Scope(scopeName = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return configureRestTemplate(builder);
}

private RestTemplate configureRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory()));
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
    interceptors.add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
        interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    return restTemplate;
}

The code for the API call side is as follows:
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

.
.
.
private <T, U> U exchangeData(URI uri, T data, Class<U> clazz, HttpHeaders requestHeaders, HttpMethod method,
                              boolean... errorCustomization) {
    HttpEntity<T> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(data, requestHeaders);
    ResponseEntity<U> response = null;
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, method, requestEntity, clazz);

    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        List<ErrorModel> errorDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        errorDetails.add(new ErrorModel(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage()));
        LOG.error("Error while calling external service", e);
        throw applicationErrorConfig.createExternalException(ApiExternalErrorType.SERVER_INTERNAL_ERROR,
                errorDetails);

    }
    restErrorManagerUtil.handleExternalServerErrorForComposite(data, response.getBody(), errorCustomization);
    return response.getBody();
}

Adding the stack traces also
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://xxxx**********************": Connect to https://xxxx********************** [domain/ip] failed: Operation timed out
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.createResourceAccessException(RestTemplate.java:888)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:868)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$$SpringCGLIB$$0.exchange(<generated>)
    at com.ai.loyalty.common.utils.ExtRestInvocationUtil.exchangeData(ExtRestInvocationUtil.java:115)
    at com.ai.loyalty.common.utils.ExtRestInvocationUtil.getData(ExtRestInvocationUtil.java:107)
    at com.ai.loyalty.common.clients.impl.LoyaltyClientImpl.getAccountSummary(LoyaltyClientImpl.java:135)
    at com.ai.loyalty.services.impl.LoyaltyMembershipServiceImpl.getAccountSummary(LoyaltyMembershipServiceImpl.java:104)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:699)
    at com.ai.loyalty.services.impl.LoyaltyMembershipServiceImpl$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getAccountSummary(<generated>)
    at com.ai.loyalty.controllers.LoyaltyMembershipController.getAccountSummaryV3(LoyaltyMembershipController.java:411)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.ai.loyalty.common.application.filters.JsonContentTypeValidationFilter.doFilterInternal(JsonContentTypeValidationFilter.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.ai.loyalty.config.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:26)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.ai.loyalty.common.application.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:145)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.v6_0.OpenTelemetryHandlerMappingFilter.doFilter(OpenTelemetryHandlerMappingFilter.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:735)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to https://xxxx********************** [domain/ip] failed: Operation timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.lambda$connectSocket$0(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:281)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:280)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:240)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:189)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:450)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:162)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:172)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:142)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:113)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:116)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:862)
    ... 125 more


Share the stracktraces of the client and server applications. What kind of timeouts are you talking about exactly?

Hi @manuel,
Adding the stack traces also, please check

Which java version did you have before? < 13?

Java 11 id my older version

Are you sure that the "Amadeus API" doesnt cause the timeouts? Have you tried to downgrade to Java 17 just for testing purposes? Should be doable, as 21 vs. 17 don't differ too if you dont rely on 21 features.

To address this, I implemented a retry mechanism using RestTemplate to handle these intermittent issues gracefully.
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException;
import org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException;

public class RetryRestTemplateExample {

    private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 3;
    private static final long BACKOFF_INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 second

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public String fetchDataWithRetries(String url) {
        int retries = 0;
        while (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
            try {
                String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
                return result;
            } catch (HttpServerErrorException | ResourceAccessException e) {
                // Handle specific exceptions that indicate transient issues
                System.out.println("Attempt #" + (retries + 1) + " failed: " + e.getMessage());
                retries++;
                if (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
                    System.out.println("Retrying in " + BACKOFF_INTERVAL + " milliseconds...");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(BACKOFF_INTERVAL);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null; // or throw exception, depending on your use case
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RetryRestTemplateExample example = new RetryRestTemplateExample();
        String url = "http://example.com/api/data";
        String data = example.fetchDataWithRetries(url);
        if (data != null) {
            System.out.println("Data fetched successfully: " + data);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to fetch data after retries.");
        }
    }
}

Explanation: In this example, I've created a RetryRestTemplateExample class that encapsulates the retry logic within the fetchDataWithRetries method. The method attempts to fetch data from a specified URL using RestTemplate. If it encounters a HttpServerErrorException or ResourceAccessException, it retries up to MAX_RETRIES times, with a BACKOFF_INTERVAL pause between retries. This helps in handling transient issues such as timeouts or network glitches gracefully.
Conclusion: If you're facing intermittent issues with RestTemplate, implementing a retry mechanism like this can be a useful approach to improve reliability. Adjust the MAX_RETRIES and BACKOFF_INTERVAL values based on your specific use case and network conditions.
Feel free to try this approach and adapt it as needed for your application's requirements.

It seems like that your application cannot connect to the application running Amadeus, as you receive a ResourceAccessException (and not a HttpClient/ServerException).
I have two wild guesses:

As you upgrade from Java 11 to Java 21, you might have run into the following bug: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8320261 It shows that SSL handshakes fail. A workaround so far is setting jdk.tls.client.enableSessionTicketExtension=false.
That some kind of proxy/firewall/reverseproxy can't handle the work load between your two applications and/or is doing some weird stuff?
Are you sure that the Amadeus API doesnt cause the timeouts?
Have you tried to downgrade one of your applications to Java 17? Do you have timeout issues as well?


I tried the above, but still having the issue
